Ros_control not activating diff drive controller
I created a custom controller, and when launched the logs at the terminal where gazebo is launched show that it's configured and activated. When i try using the diff_drive_controller, the ros_control is stuck at trying to configure the controller. all controller processes show "controller activated and configured" then die according to the terminal where the controller configurations were launched. when i check the states of both (joint state publisher and diff drive controller), it does show active, even though both never register as activated in ros_control. The topics of both controllers are created and available when i run: ros2 topic list
My controller configuration file:
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 1000
    use_sim_time: true

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster
    
    dfdr_bumperbot_controller:
      type: diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController

    simple_velocity_controller: # doesnt get initialized in my launch file.
      type: velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController


dfdr_bumperbot_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    type: diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController
    left_wheel_names: ["wheel_left_joint"]
    right_wheel_names: ["wheel_right_joint"]

    wheel_separation: 0.17
    wheel_radius: 0.033

    wheel_separation_multiplier: 1.0
    left_wheel_radius_multiplier: 1.0
    right_wheel_radius_multiplier: 1.0

    base_frame_id: base_footprint
    pose_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 1.0e-3, 1.0e-3, 1.0e-3, 0.01]
    twist_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 1.0e-3, 1.0e-3, 1.0e-3, 0.01]
    publish rate: 50.0

    position_feedback: true
    open_loop: false
    enable_odom_tf: true

    cmd_vel_timeout: 0.25
    publish_limited_velocity: true
    velocity_rolling_window_size: 10

    linear.x.has_velocity_limits: true
    linear.x.has_acceleration_limits: true
    linear.x.has_jerk_limits: false
    linear.x.max_velocity: 1.0
    linear.x.min_velocity: -0.5
    linear.x.max_acceleration: 0.8
    linear.x.min_acceleration: -0.4

    angular.z.has_velocity_limits: true
    angular.z.has_acceleration_limits: true
    angular.z.has_jerk_limits: false
    angular.z.max_velocity: 1.7
    angular.z.min_velocity: -1.7
    angular.z.max_acceleration: 1.5
    angular.z.min_acceleration: -1.5


simple_velocity_controller: 
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - wheel_left_joint
      - wheel_right_joint

controller output (gz_ros_control):
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/kingade/.ros/log/2024-07-08-19-10-50-004368-kingade-HP-EliteBook-x360-1040-G6-5334
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [spawner-1]: process started with pid [5337]
[INFO] [spawner-2]: process started with pid [5338]
[spawner-1] [INFO] [1720462250.837638407] [spawner_dfdr_bumperbot_controller]: Loaded dfdr_bumperbot_controller
[spawner-1] [INFO] [1720462250.864107938] [spawner_dfdr_bumperbot_controller]: Configured and activated dfdr_bumperbot_controller
[spawner-2] [INFO] [1720462250.867505400] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Loaded joint_state_broadcaster
[spawner-2] [INFO] [1720462250.901485726] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Configured and activated joint_state_broadcaster
[INFO] [spawner-1]: process has finished cleanly [pid 5337]
[INFO] [spawner-2]: process has finished cleanly [pid 5338]

controller_manager output:
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1720462250.789024281] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'dfdr_bumperbot_controller'
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1720462250.815325620] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1720462250.839983470] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'dfdr_bumperbot_controller'
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1720462250.869136880] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1720462250.869232708] [joint_state_broadcaster]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published

controller launch fie
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, GroupAction
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch.conditions import IfCondition, UnlessCondition


def generate_launch_description():

    use_python_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        "use_python",
        default_value="True",
        description="Choose whether to use the python script or Cpp script."
    )

    wheel_radius_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        "wheel_radius",
        default_value="0.033",
        description="Radius of wheels"
    )

    wheel_sep_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        "wheel_seperation",
        default_value="0.17",
        description="Distance between the center of both wheels."
    )

    use_simple_controller_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        "use_simple_controller",
        default_value="False",
        description="Use custom simple controller "
    )

    

    use_python = LaunchConfiguration("use_python")
    wheel_radius = LaunchConfiguration("wheel_radius")
    wheel_sep = LaunchConfiguration("wheel_seperation")
    use_simple_controller = LaunchConfiguration("use_simple_controller")

    diff_drive_controller_spawner = Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='spawner',
        arguments=['dfdr_bumperbot_controller', '--controller-manager', '/controller_manager'],
        condition=UnlessCondition(use_simple_controller)
    )

    
    joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='spawner',
        arguments=['joint_state_broadcaster', '--controller-manager', '/controller_manager']
    )

    

    simple_controller = GroupAction(
        condition=IfCondition(use_simple_controller),
        actions=[
            Node(
                package='controller_manager',
                executable='spawner',
                arguments=['simple_velocity_controller', '--controller-manager', '/controller_manager'],
            ),

            Node(
                package="bumperbot_controller",
                executable="simple_controller.py",
            )
        ]
    )


    ld = LaunchDescription()
    ld.add_action(use_simple_controller_arg)
    ld.add_action(diff_drive_controller_spawner)
    ld.add_action(simple_controller)
    ld.add_action(use_python_arg)
    ld.add_action(wheel_radius_arg)
    ld.add_action(wheel_sep_arg)
    ld.add_action(joint_state_broadcaster_spawner)
    return ld

Full Controller Logs
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.258183270] [GazeboSimROS2ControlPlugin]: robot_param_node is robot_state_publisher
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.258211261] [GazeboSimROS2ControlPlugin]: robot_param_node is robot_description
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.287597526] [gz_ros_control]: connected to service!! robot_state_publisher asking for robot_description
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.287960989] [gz_ros_control]: Received URDF from param server
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.297612088] [gz_ros_control]: The position_proportional_gain has been set to: 0.1
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.297662189] [gz_ros_control]: Loading joint: wheel_right_joint
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.297672661] [gz_ros_control]:    State:
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.297687271] [gz_ros_control]:         position
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.297695468] [gz_ros_control]:         velocity
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.297701815] [gz_ros_control]:    Command:
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.297706632] [gz_ros_control]:         velocity
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.297719518] [gz_ros_control]: Loading joint: wheel_left_joint
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.297723564] [gz_ros_control]:    State:
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.297727068] [gz_ros_control]:         position
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.297730515] [gz_ros_control]:         velocity
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.297733692] [gz_ros_control]:    Command:
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.297736699] [gz_ros_control]:         velocity
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.297774590] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'GazeboSimSystem' 
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [WARN] [1721298505.297784451] [gz_ros_control]: On init...
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.297818833] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'GazeboSimSystem'
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.297844065] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'GazeboSimSystem' 
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.297846731] [gz_ros_control]: System Successfully configured!
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.297851435] [resource_manager]: Successful 'configure' of hardware 'GazeboSimSystem'
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.297854417] [resource_manager]: 'activate' hardware 'GazeboSimSystem' 
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.297856406] [resource_manager]: Successful 'activate' of hardware 'GazeboSimSystem'
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.297860251] [gz_ros_control]: Loading controller_manager
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.322401013] [controller_manager]: Subscribing to '/robot_description' topic for robot description.
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298505.332903203] [controller_manager]: Received robot description from topic.
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [WARN] [1721298505.332937689] [controller_manager]: ResourceManager has already loaded an urdf file. Ignoring attempt to reload a robot description file.
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Wrn] [Component.hh:144] Trying to serialize component with data type [N3sdf3v145WorldE], which doesn't have `operator<<`. Component will not be serialized.
[ruby $(which gz) sim-2] [GUI] [Wrn] [Component.hh:189] Trying to deserialize component with data type [N3sdf3v145WorldE], which doesn't have `operator>>`. Component will not be deserialized.
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Msg] Resource path resolve service on [/gazebo/resource_paths/resolve].
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Msg] Resource paths published on [/gazebo/resource_paths].
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Msg] Server control service on [/server_control].
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Msg] Found no publishers on /stats, adding root stats topic
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Msg] Found no publishers on /clock, adding root clock topic
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Dbg] [SimulationRunner.cc:547] Creating PostUpdate worker threads: 4
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Dbg] [SimulationRunner.cc:558] Creating postupdate worker thread (0)
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Dbg] [SimulationRunner.cc:558] Creating postupdate worker thread (1)
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Dbg] [SimulationRunner.cc:558] Creating postupdate worker thread (2)
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Dbg] [SystemManager.cc:74] Loaded system [gz_ros2_control::GazeboSimROS2ControlPlugin] for entity [10]
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Dbg] [UserCommands.cc:1311] Created entity [10] named [bumperbot]
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Dbg] [SDFFeatures.cc:328] Mesh construction from an SDF has not been implemented yet for dartsim. Use AttachMeshShapeFeature to use mesh shapes.
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Dbg] [SDFFeatures.cc:843] The geometry element of collision [base_footprint_fixed_joint_lump__base_link_collision] couldn't be created
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Msg] Serving scene information on [/world/default/scene/info]
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Msg] Serving graph information on [/world/default/scene/graph]
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Msg] Serving full state on [/world/default/state]
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Msg] Serving full state (async) on [/world/default/state_async]
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Msg] Publishing scene information on [/world/default/scene/info]
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Msg] Publishing entity deletions on [/world/default/scene/deletion]
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Msg] Publishing state changes on [/world/default/state]
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Msg] Publishing pose messages on [/world/default/pose/info]
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Msg] Publishing dynamic pose messages on [/world/default/dynamic_pose/info]
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Dbg] [EntityComponentManager.cc:1655] Updated state thread iterators: 8 threads processing around 4 entities each.
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Dbg] [SimulationRunner.cc:574] Exiting postupdate worker thread (0[Dbg] [SimulationRunner.cc:574] [Dbg] [SimulationRunner.cc:574] Exiting postupdate worker thread (20[Dbg] [SimulationRunner.cc:574] 0))x
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] 1)
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] 
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] 
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Dbg] [SimulationRunner.cc:547] Creating PostUpdate worker threads: 5
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Dbg] [SimulationRunner.cc:558] Creating postupdate worker thread (0)
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Dbg] [SimulationRunner.cc:558] Creating postupdate worker thread (1)
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Dbg] [SimulationRunner.cc:558] Creating postupdate worker thread (2)
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [Dbg] [SimulationRunner.cc:558] Creating postupdate worker thread (3)
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298534.236041412] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298534.263166531] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'dfdr_bumperbot_controller'
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298534.288704911] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'joint_state_broadcaster'
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298534.288895087] [joint_state_broadcaster]: 'joints' or 'interfaces' parameter is empty. All available state interfaces will be published
[ruby $(which gz) sim-1] [INFO] [1721298534.313372492] [controller_manager]: Configuring controller 'dfdr_bumperbot_controller'


which ROS distro are you using? please post the full console output of ign/gz/gazebo_ros2_control (whatever you are using).

I'm using jazzy. and my question would be updated by the time you read this

What do you mean by ros_control is stuck at trying to configure the controller? It seems to be configured, but not activated. What is the output of ros2 control list_controllers? With which arguments are you calling the spawners?

@ChristophFroehlich, the output from ros2 control list_controllers shows that they're both activated, but it never confirms to be activated in the terminal i launch gazebo from. the controllers' processes also die, which shouldn't be so. I've updated my question with the controller launch file.

I created a simple controller, which works perfectly (the simple_velocity_controller), and i get a confirmation in the terminal where gazebo is launched from: activate successful

from your console output snippets there is no hint that the processes die? only the spawners reach their supposed lifetime.

Yes, sorry that's a misinterpretation on my end. @ChristophFroehlich

which means that everything works as expected now?

No. The gazebo terminal logs still never confirm activated. @ChristophFroehlich

then please share the full log (not only the few lines here: controller_manager output)

@ChristophFroehlich I've updated with full logs. I really appreciate the help by the way

can it be that your controller hangs in the on_activate() method? because the CM not even reports the joint_state_broadcaster being activated.
but what is strange then that ros2 control list_controllers tells activated?! Are you sure that the controller does not work, or is it activated but only the message is missing from the CM?

@ChristophFroehlich I have confirmed that it isn't working. Usually it also shows a 'configure successful' log, but none are showed. So I believe the problem may be from the configuring

you are right, then problem in on_configure. but ros2 control reports it as active, or not?

yes, ros2 control list_controllers demand reports that both are active

@ChristophFroehlich

but then the controller should be working as expected, and you are only missing the prompt in the console of the controller_manager?

@ChristophFroehlich Yes. My custom controller that i built using the joint velocity controller worked though, showing the prompt. It showed both a configure successful and activated successful while this is stuck on configuring. No matter what command I send using this differential drive controller, it doesnt move the bot.
